# Jquery Autocomplete on Asp.net MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

im new using asp.net mvc so i am trying to use the jquery UI autocomplete. here is my code

```
        $.ajax({ url: '../Empresa/cargar_sectoresindustriales', dataType: "json", method: "POST", cache: false, data: { action: "load_sector" } })
        .fail(function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { console.log("Status: " + textStatus + " Error: " + errorThrown); })
        .done(function (data) {
            console.log(data)
            if (data == 0) {
                qElement.val("No existen empresas");
                qElement.prop('readonly', true);
            } else {
                qElement.autocomplete({
                    source: function (request, response) {
                        var term = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term)
                            , startsWithMatcher = new RegExp("^" + term, "i")
                            , startsWith = $.grep(data, function (value) {
                                return startsWithMatcher.test(value.label || value.value || value);
                            })
                            , containsMatcher = new RegExp(term, "i")
                            , contains = $.grep(data, function (value) {
                                return $.inArray(value, startsWith) < 0 &&
                                    containsMatcher.test(value.label || value.value || value);
                            });

                        response(startsWith.concat(contains));
                    }
                });
            }
        })
```

i have no errors but still dont work. This is the console log 
[console log response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tT5k9.png)

any ideas

thanks.

Comment: You seem to wrapping the plugin inside a ajax request, in the jquery ui doc the ajax call is in the init of the plugin :

https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp

Comment: Check example on official plugin site https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote you don't need to use ajax, filtering have to be performed on backend to avoid transferring too much data.

Comment: i use this example https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ and also dont work. i think if maybe had something to do with the nuget package or with asp.net